# Poor concurrency and perf on multiple GPUs VM (running CodeLlama locally using Ollama)

Tags: llm, llama-2, gpu

I am trying to figure out if self hosting CodeLlama on a sufficiently powerful multi-GPU machine can be cost effective for my specific product needs.

However, when I go from 1 GPU to 4 GPU VM, I see performance decrease as well as I do not see any concurrency benefits, and it is very puzzling!

Here is what I have tried till now:

Installed and run CodeLlama:7b model locally using **[Ollama](https://ollama.ai/)** in each of below scenarios:
[image]

Here are my conclusions so far:

- With single V100 GPU, the response time increases almost linearly as number of concurrent requests increase (its almost Mean = 1.3 x Number of concurrent req)
- With 4 V100 GPUs, the response times are worse (2x or more compared to single GPU VM)
- CPU and RAM barely get utilized | While GPU Memory loads the Model.
- When running with 4 GPUs: First GPU (device (0)) shoots to 70% usage, while other 3 remain around 15% usage only.
- I do not see any concurrency benefits at all. Have tried to clean slate the VM and start from beginning with Ubuntu as well as Cent OS.

Here are my main questions:

1. How can a single GPU machine performs better for 1 request, than 4 GPU VM?
   [image]
2. Why no concurrency benefits with 4 GPU VM with 24 cores and sufficient memory?
   [image]

I am using Apache Bench to test.

I have just started to explore this space, please excuse the stupidity of my questions if missing something basic. I am looking for unlocking concurrency and perf on multi GPU VM.